# DuckDuckGo and search date ranges

Tags: duckduckgo

DuckDuckGo's ability to search across date ranges appears to be very limited in comparison with Google.

There appears to be no way in DuckDuckGo to specify search date ranges, or any periods other than *any time*, *past day*, *past week*, *past month*.

Is this indeed the case? Or do they (DuckDuckGo) just not make it obvious, for some reason?

Comment: As ridiculous as it may sound, supposedly they've been working on this _feature_ for over 7 seven years now (you can look for yourself at [this thread](https://duck.co/forum/thread/1678/filter-search-results-by-date) on their forums). Doesn't look too good, right? So still no real alternative for Google with its insidious ways for us, I guess. That also explains why there is totality of like 13 questions here tagged with `duckduckgo` and the best have like 5 upvotes. Real throngs of people must be using it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the case: I can totally use "Custom date range", and it is out there in a totally obvious way.

Maybe you are using Tor Browser and this changes the website behaviour?

[image: custom date range]